# Why is resource attribute undefined when performing a where query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following:

**collection:**

```
schedules
  - uuid
  - schoolUuid
  - userUuid
  - requestUuid
```

**Security Rules**

```
 match /schedules/{scheduleUuid}
    function isAuthor(){
       return resource.data.userUuid == request.auth.uid 
    }
    function isAdmin(){
     let schoolUuid = resource.data.schoolUuid
     return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(request.auth.uid)).data[schoolUuid] == true
    }
    read: if isAuth() && (isAuthor() || isAdmin())
    create: if isAuth()
    update: if isAuth() && (isAuthor() || isAdmin())
```

**Queries**

As an admin, this test pass:

```
 const db = firebaseDB({ uid: schoolAdmin.uuid, email: clinicAdmin.email });
 const scheduleRef = db
      .collection('schedules')
      .where('schoolUuid', '==', 'some-school-uuid');
 await firebase.assertSucceeds(scheduleRef.get());
```

As an author, this test also pass:

```
 const db = firebaseDB({ uid: schoolEmployee.uuid, email: schoolEmployee.email });
 const scheduleRef = db
      .collection('schedules')
      .where('userUuid', '==', 'some-employeeUuid');
 await firebase.assertSucceeds(scheduleRef.get());
```

Now, as an admin or author, the following query fails:

```
 const db = firebaseDB({ uid: schoolEmployee.uuid, email: schoolEmployee.email }); // either schoolEmployee or schoolAdmin
 const scheduleRef = db
      .collection('schedules')
      .where('requestUuid', '==', 'some-requestUuid');
 await firebase.assertSucceeds(scheduleRef.get());
```

It gives the following error: "userUuid is undefined on object"
[image]

**Expectation**

I expect resource.data to contain the userUuid, schoolUuid, requestUuid. I noticed that on a "where" query the only attribute that is available on resource.data is the one I'm querying on. For example, if I do:
`db.collection('schedules').where('schoolUuid', '==', 'some-uuid')`
Only the schoolUuid is available in my security rules, if I try to access userUuid or requestUuid, it gives undefined.

This is not the case when I query the document specifically:
`db.collections('schedules').doc('schedule-uuid')`
In this case, all attributes are available in the security rule. It seems the issue is when I do a where query. By the documentation:
"Query constraints match security rules constraints". I wonder if the reason why it is failing is because I don't have a security rule for `'requestUuid', '==', 'some-requestUuid'`

I would appreciate any clarifications. It seems I'm misundersanding something important here. I have been using [this reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code of the client query that doesn't work the way you expect.  Rules themselves don't do anything without being matched to specific queries that should be allowed or rejected by the rules.

Comment: Hi Doug, I continued poking around and simplified my question. I identified where my code is failing and I'm not able to tell why. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `resource` in security rules, it refers to the specific document **within the collection of the closes match** that's being read or written.  It doesn't refer to any parent documents.  If you need to refer to any other document outside of the one specifically matched by a rule, you need to use a `get()`, as described in the documentation for [accessing other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).  Since your nested document depends on the contents of a different document (even if its a parent document), it requires a `get()`.

Comment: Thank you Doug. My event document contains the schoolUuid attribute, shouldn't I still be able to access resource.data.schoolUuid from the event doc? Based on my understanding, I shouldn't have to get it from the parent schedule doc if the event contains it. Isn't that right? I wonder if the fact that it is nested makes resource.data undefined? If so, would it be a better approach to make the events a collection at the same level as schedules and store a foreign key on every event to point to their parent schedule?

Comment: I can't see the data in your database, but the results you're showing here suggest that your events document doesn't have a correct schoolUuid field.

Comment: Hi Doug, I appreciate for taking the time to look at my question. I just added two images of my data above in the question. I have the schoolUuid in every event document, yet the  resource.data is undefined.